# Java Swing adding component issues

Tags: java, swing, label

I'm approaching the study of `Swing` java library.
The following simple code, "in most of cases", is not working (see pic 1 below) (`label1` somehow disappear or is not added to the `contentPane` at all)
Very rarely it works (I had to run and stop it many times to catch the right result).  (pic 2)
Sometimes nothing displayed. (pic3)

I know it should be handled with a layout manager but i'm interested in understanding why it happens rather than workaround this.

I'm experiencing this issue within Eclipse on both Windows 7 and 8.1

Thx

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JFrame finestra=new JFrame("frame title");
    finestra.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    finestra.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 700);
    finestra.setVisible(true);

    JLabel label1=new JLabel("label 1");
    finestra.add(label1);

    JLabel label2=new JLabel("label 2");
    finestra.add(label2);   
}
```

pic1: 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI1xf.jpg]]

pic2:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaWON.jpg]]

pic3:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvUoy.jpg]]

Comment: This repeatedly shows `pic1` for me.

Comment: 'JFrame` uses [BorederLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) by default, and you are adding 2 labels to `BorderLyout.CENTER`, so they overwrite each other. Try `finestra.add(label1, BorderLayout.NORTH);`

Comment: _Very rarely it works_: Construct and manipulate Swing GUI objects _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: As I said this question arises in the study and not in the problem solving and therefore, as it may seem silly, it is at least an objective to frame the issue in the right context.
I understand that each area of ​​a layout manager can accommodate only one component but despite this it may happen that (seldom, as already mentioned) the two components are shown both.
Perhaps an anomaly of the event dispatch thread is the cause of this phenomenon but I am unable to comprehend more.

Answer (score 0):

JFrame.add(Component) adds given component to "center" of JFrame's content pane. So, when you add label1, it is added to "center". And when you add label2, it replaces label1 in "center". That's why you end up with label2 only. Try below code and see:

```
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame finestra=new JFrame("frame title");
    finestra.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    finestra.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 700);

    JLabel label1=new JLabel("label 1");
    finestra.add(label1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JLabel label2=new JLabel("label 2");
    finestra.add(label2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // Call setVisible(true) after labels are layed out.
    finestra.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```